# How does a electrical device draw its rated current?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, high-voltage, current-source, physics

I am learning electronics and this question has been bugging me quite a bit. If I have a device, let us say rated at 6 volts and 350 mA, this means the device will work when there is a potential difference of 6 volts across the lamp and it has 350 mA flowing through it right?

In household circuits, the power outlets are usually at 220V and the current it will draw will depend on the resistor of our device no? How will our lamp with the above rating work in this case?

Comment: A lamp will present a resistance (or impedance if AC) to the power lines such that the correct amount of current flows as per ohm's law.

Comment: "*6 Volts and 350 mA, this means the device will work when there is a potential difference of 6 volts across the lamp and it has 350 mA flowing through it right?*" Note quite. Since most things are powered from (constant) voltage sources, not (constant) current sources, it is usually meant to be interpreted in the following context: Being rated at 6V and 350mA means that it requires 6V to run and if you apply 6V to it, 350mA will flow through it in response.

Comment: If it were intended to be powered by a current source, things would be reversed: It requires 350mA flowing through it to function and to force that amount of current requires 6V be applied. It might seem like a subtle difference for a lamp which is constant power but not all loads are (like a computer or a motor). So for things expected to be powered by a constant load that 6V must remain the same, but the current could change in operation. Again, reversed for things expected to be powered by a current source.

Comment: @user1850479, but wouldn't the lamp have constant resistance/impedance? I don't think it can change that to ensure the right current flows though it

Comment: @Dixshants The words user1859479 used hold true for both variable and fixed resistors, so you're reading more into the words than what is actually written. But if you want to get into it, the resistance of the filament increases as it gets hotter and since the filament runs much hotter than room temperature, an incandescent lamp filament has a considerably different cold and hot resistance. Constant resistance is just an ideal model that is easy to work with linear mathematics.

Comment: There are no truly temperature independent real resistances and in the case of a lamp filament constant resistance doesn't actually matter so no material effort is made to make it constant. It would be wrong to assume that just because a resistance exists in nature, that it is constant with respect to temperature, voltage, and other factors. Constant resistance is just an ideal model that is simple to work with because it uses linear mathematics. When humans make resistors as electronic components, we specifically try to make them adhere to this ideal so that they are easy to design with.

Comment: it may help if you think about it this way ... `the 6 V is able to push 350 mA through the load` ... it also means that a higher voltage will be able to push more current through the same load

Comment: Are you asking what happens when you plug a 6v light into a 220v supply?  Or asking how different loads are matched to different voltages? I interpreted your question as the latter, but from your comments below it sounds like you meant the former?

Comment: Notice however that a LED (as commonly used in modern lamps) has quite different characteristics to a traditional lamp's resistive load.  Both will be quickly destroyed by 220V though.

Answer (score 3):

First, ratings can be weird.  Some devices (like consumer-grade light bulbs and vacuum tubes) have the *nominal* ratings given.  Some devices (like semiconductors) have the *maximum* ratings given.  Really well-specified devices will have both nominal and maximum ratings, and for things like light bulbs, may even come with charts giving you a performance vs. voltage *and* a lifetime vs. voltage, so you can make your own decisions.

If you buy a light bulb that's advertised as 6V, 350mA, then it should have *around** 6V applied, and it will draw *around* 350mA.  Apply more voltage and the current will probably go up, apply less and it'll probably go down.  If that bulb is being lit up by mains power, then either there's a box in the middle that drops the voltage, or there's a bunch of them in series (i.e., 36 or 37 6V bulbs, in series, should run off of 220V as long as they all warm up about the same speed).

Ratings aside, in general any two-terminal load will pull a certain amount of current given a certain amount of voltage.  This is just basic physics -- put a voltage on something, and *it* determines the amount of current it'll consume.  A corollary to this is that if you force a certain amount of current through a two-terminal device, *it'll* determine how much voltage it generates to oppose the current.  With only access to the two terminals you cannot arbitrarily choose both the voltage and current that'll flow.

*Usually* a simple device like a light bulb will pull more current with increasing voltage.  However there's other things -- like anything with a switching regulator in it -- that may have a section of its operating curve where increasing voltage will make it pull *less* current, or the current will be flat for a while.

Getting back to your light bulb: if you plug a 6V plain old incandescent bulb *directly* into a 220V source, then it'll die in milliseconds, possibly violently enough to damage things around it.  Ditto almost any 6V LED bulb -- although typically LED bulbs have driver circuits, and one could, conceivably**, design a driver circuit to work from 6V to 220V.

* "Around" in this case meaning \$\pm\$20%, but it's a squishy number -- you can get a dim glow from a 12V bulb run on 6V, and a 3V bulb on 6V will be *really bright*, possibly for hours or days before it burns out.

** Either as a joke or because there were really stupid specifications to be met.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered this. It helped me a lot. I was under the impression that we make randomly rated devices in terms of voltage and current because there are so many different voltages that the outlet could be at (and the device on the inside did something to drop the volts). But I guess for an entire countrty, that outlet voltage is the same, so all devices will be rated at 220V

Comment: More and more devices are being designed to work from 100V to 240V, so they can be plugged in anywhere.  But yes -- because voltages tend to be the same country-wide or region-wide, the market for things like light bulbs or juice mixers can be big.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 things to consider for a lamp. The rated voltage, the rated current, the resistance of the lamp and the power produced by the lamp.

In simple terms what is fixed is the resistance of the lamp. As you increase the Voltage across that resistance the current increases. These values are related mathematically by Ohms law. This states that V=IR. Voltage is current times resistances this can be rearranged to give you the current for a resistance at a particular voltage as I=V/R.

Your 6V lamp rated at 350ma therefore has a resistance of R=V/I of 6/0.35 or about 17 ohms. It will produce an output power of Volts x Amps = 2.1W

If you connect this resistance to 240V you get 240/17A = 14A. This produces power of about 3388W which explodes the bulb.

A 240V 100W bulb is made with a resistance of about 780 ohms giving you a current of about 300ma.

By making bulbs with different resistances you can make them suitable for different voltages.

Answer (score 0):

A 6 V lamp plugged into a 220 V socket will draw roughly 37 times its rated current, or about 12.8 A. However, it will do so for a very short period of time before the filament is vaporized and the lamp is destroyed.

Comment: Possibly destroyed explosively. Learnt this plugging my lego light brick into the mains at a very young age. Don't try this at home.

Comment: But we still do it right? Why is it that lamps don't melt when drawing power from the main outlet?

Comment: The actual amount of current it'll draw depends on the device -- although at 220V vs. 6V, "lots and lots more" will be accurate.  For instance, if it's an LED with a simple bridge, then the current will (briefly) rise exponentially with voltage.  If it's an incandescent light, the resistance will go up with temperature, so the current will (briefly) rise as something like \$\sqrt[n]{V}\$, where \$n\$ is something like 3 or 4 (I can't remember).  The key word in all of this, however, is "briefly", perhaps accompanied by "ball of plasma".

Comment: "But we still do it right?" No, if we want a lamp to run off 230V we use one designed to do that, not one designed to run off 6V.